# Build JavaFX application with preloader

Tags: gradle, javafx, build, build-process, preloader

I use IntelliJ IDEA IDE and I want use the Gradle system as a build system in my JavaFX application. I want to create preloader for my program and pack it with program into one jar file. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/applications-with-a-preloader-project-organization-and-packaging.html?origin=old_help) says that I must have at least two modules: application and preloader. How build the JavaFX application with preloader by using gradle system?

Comment: You might want to look into the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) (I haven't tried it myself).  Perhaps contact the [maintainer of the project](https://github.com/FibreFoX) directly if you are having difficulty getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator and maintainer of the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

You don't need to create some preloader, it is used while the JVM loads the libraries and while booting all classloaders, but you don't have to create some preloader.

There is a conflict in interests here: you are using two systems to generate that javafx-appliaction, one is the gradle-build-system, the other is your IntelliJ IDEA-IDE. There is a JavaFX-plugin for IDEA, which does some things, and there is the gradle-plugin i wrote, which does some things withing normal gradle-development-cycle.

The javafx-gradle-plugin is IDE-agnostic, so you are not required to have some IDEA-plugins enabled.

To have some example with included usage of proguard, [you can see it at github](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin/tree/master/examples/javafx-proguard-gradle).

Comment: I apologise for my inattention. I clarified my question.

Comment: @Antonio it is not adviced to create a single jar, because that preloader should be lightweight, which isn't when residing inside some fat-jar. To package your application using javafx-gradle-plugin, just call `gradle jfxJar` or `gradle jfxNative` (might be able to select in your IDE)